# Using beautifulsoup to parse tag with some text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Some html code contains some `dt` tags like follows:

```
<dt>PLZ:</dt>
<dd>
8047
</dd>
```

I want to find the text in the `dd` tag following the `dt` tag with the text `PLZ:`. According to documentation I am trying the following:

```
number = BeautifulSoup(text).find("dt",text="PLZ:").findNextSiblings("dd")
```

with `text` the above string, but all I get is an empty list instead the number I am looking for (as string of course). Maybe I misunderstand the documentation?

Comment: I'd wager `PLZ:` isn't matching (maybe you're too strict?).  To debug, try reducing `PLZ:` to something minimal -- if it matches anything at all, add some of `PLZ:` back until you get what you're expecting.

Comment: PLZ: is matching actually. i.e. the part `BeautifulSoup(text).find("dt",text="PLZ:")` returns an object that is printed as `PLZ:`. Only the last step does not seem to work. Or at least does not work in the way I am trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so just try:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<dt>PLZ:</dt>
<dd>
8047
</dd>"""

number = BeautifulSoup(text).find("dt",text="PLZ:").parent.findNextSiblings("dd")
print BeautifulSoup(''.join(number[0]))
```

or if you find with findNext try:

```
number = BeautifulSoup(text).find("dt",text="PLZ:").parent.findNext("dd").contents[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

text = '''<dt>PLZ:</dt>
<dd>
8047
</dd>'''


BeautifulSoup(text).find("dt",text="PLZ:").parent.findNextSiblings('dd')
```